# Sort the array by Uppercase to Lowercase

Tags: php

I have the

```
$array = array("Apple", "Elephant", "Cat", "Banana", "Dog", "apple","elephant","banana","cat","dog");
```

i need to sort as

```
$array= array("Apple", "apple", "Banana", "banana", "Cat", "cat", "Dog", "dog",...);
```

Can anyone help me to get in php?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `natcasesort`to sort Uppercase to Lowercase

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are looking for [`natcasesort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php):

```
natcasesort($array);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/126461)

Comment: yes.. but for the above array am getting Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [5] => apple
    [7] => banana
    [3] => Banana
    [2] => Cat
    [8] => cat
    [9] => dog
    [4] => Dog
    [1] => Elephant
    [6] => elephant
)

Comment: whereas i need "Banana" first and "banana" next..  similarly "Dog" first and "dog" second

Comment: @user2324085 why did you accept the answer with less information and answered an hour later? But the same function?

Comment: is this ok now???  can u also tell me how to sort the string(no need array) by Uppercase to Lowercase